# Looking for a noun to describe an organized group of thieves in a sci-fi setting

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

We are trying to find a fitting name for a group of people in something we are working on that describes them well.

This group of people is essentially a very organized group of thieves that profit off of another group of merchants and adventurers by riding in their ships for free without them noticing, and then do illegal activities with ill-intent (such as exploiting, looting, stealing, selling, undercutting...)

We want to convey both their intent: illegal merchants and thieves, as well as their modus operandi: being sort of parasites to other groups by riding in their ships unnoticed for free.

One important thing about them is that they are comparable to a mafia, or organized crime, not just a simple, small operation that leeches a few resources off of others.

So far, they are called Ravagers, and we've already considered:

- Freeloaders -> Misrepresents this group as not proactive or organized. No specific goals.
- Parasites -> Too negative and also does not talk about their endgame goal or activities.
- Scrounger -> Makes them sound like beggars.
- Sycophant -> Makes them look too gullible and "dumb", also they are not flatterers or social con artists, they are just in the shadows and very organized and surgical.

Of course, as you may have noticed, this has to be a noun.

Comment: There are two different things you are combining, both of which already have English words describing them: *stowaways* and *bandits*. Have you considered combining two of these terms, like *stowaway bandits*?

Comment: Hello @PeterShor, the idea of having 2 nouns together to combine the two intents I've mentioned could be a potential solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OMG, @Peter, you've invented the noun compound.

Comment: I suggest you borrow a word that doesn't actually mean that but suggests it: such as **Bootloaders**.

Comment: **profiteers**  is a good word here.

Comment: I’d go for para-irates. Parasite  pirates ‍☠️!

Comment: as long as we're on portmanteaus, you could take *stowaway* + *buccaneer* to get *stowaneer*.

Comment: I might give them the name “Cuckoos”, after “a cuckoo in the nest”. But this is only an opinion, as are other suggestions, so I must vote to close the question.

Comment: "We are waging a war against the C3 [ **Cancerous Covert Contrabandists** ] whose gang members are **Desperados** of the most vile nature"